# start on ( condition ) in file /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf

Tags: 14.04, boot, upstart, system

I am actually trying to add a boot options to start only the filesystem or start it with the static-network-up based on some system settings.

We have a standard installation for multiple types of machines and checking for the static-network-up takes a considerable amount of time. So i was looking for a way to add an option in /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf on the start on (filesystem and static-network-up) or failsafe-boot

Is it possible to call an exterior utility (like facter) or base the option on the HOSTNAME, I have tried this without any success :

start on (filesystem and (HOSTNAME=^qz* or static-network-up)) or failsafe-boot

So, to recap. How do I add an option on this line to start with or without the static-network-up?